# How to upload images to Firebase based chat app messages with React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm currently working on a classic `react-native` chat app with a `firebase` backend. So far I have managed, that users can login with their social media accounts and joining multiple chatrooms, the only thing missing is that users should be able to upload images, either from the library or directly taking by the camera.

Here is my firebase code to store the messages:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null);
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[] | null>(null);
const {chatRoom} = route.params;

const sendMessage = async () => {
  const timeStamp = serverTimestamp();
  const id = `${Date.now()}`;
  const _doc: Message = {
    _id: id,
    chatRoomId: chatRoom._id,
    timeStamp,
    message,
    user: {
      name: user?.displayName || null,
      avatar: user?.photoURL || null,
      email: user?.email || null,
    },
  };
  setMessage('');

  try {
    await addDoc(
      collection(doc(firestoreDB, 'chatRooms', chatRoom._id), 'messages'),
     _doc,
    );
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
};

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const msgQuery = query(
    collection(firestoreDB, 'chatRooms', chatRoom._id, 'messages'),
    orderBy('timeStamp', 'asc'),
  );

  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(msgQuery, querySnap => {
    const updMsg: Message[] = querySnap.docs.map(
      doc => doc.data() as Message,
    );
    setMessages(updMsg);
    setIsLoading(false);
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, [chatRoom._id]);
```

I was thinking to add the image to the message `object`, something like this:

```
const _doc: Message = {
  _id: id,
  chatRoomId: chatRoom._id,
  timeStamp,
  message,
  messageImg: {
     src: '' | null    
  }
  user: {
    name: user?.displayName || null,
    avatar: user?.photoURL || null,
    email: user?.email || null,
  },
};
```

but I guess, that is not the way to do it? So my question is, should I upload the image to a `firebase-storage`-database and then somehow connect the image from the database to the message from the message collection by checking the Id? If yes, I would be glad for an example...

just for information, I've already added the packages [@react-native-firebase/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/storage) and [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker)

I hope you can help me out! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> should I upload the image to a firebase-storage-database and then
> somehow connect the image from the database to the message from the
> message collection by checking the Id? If yes, I would be glad for an example...

Yes, a very common approach is to upload images to the [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage?hl=en&authuser=0) service, generate a download URL and store it into the Firestore document corresponding to either the user's profile (for an avatar) or to the chat message (for an image linked to the message).

You'll find in the doc [a full example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en&authuser=0#full_example) of image uploading followed by the download URL generation.

---

Another possibility, instead of using a Download URL, is to store in Firestore the path of the image within Cloud Storage. Then, when you want to display the image in your app you can use the corresponding [methods of the JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk).